# Difference between printenv $PATH and printenv ($PATH)

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh

What is the difference between `printenv x` and `printenv ($x)`

I'm on zsh and when I try `printenv $PATH` I see just the PATH env variable as the output but when I try `printenv ($PATH)` i get all the env variables as the output.

Comment: Start here: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

What's common in the variants you posted in the title of your question, is that neither does make sense. From the *printenv* manpage, the use is

> printenv [OPTION]... [VARIABLE]...

Neither `$PATH` nor `($PATH)` is the name of a variable.

`$PATH` would expand to a colon-separated list of directories.

The opening parenthese of `($PATH)` would signal to zsh, that it is part of globbing (see filename expansion in the zsh man-page), and zsh is expecting valid expansion flags after the parenthese. The exact reaction of zsh in this case (error message, or just output of an empty line) depends on your value of `PATH` and how you configured your zsh to behave in case of failed globbing.

You can see what is actually going on in your case, when you turn on command tracing with `set -x`.

What would make sense is to write

```
printenv PATH
```

since `PATH` indeed is a variable.